# jquery fadeout and fadein how to not flashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have that jquery code

```
$(function(){
$('.efectfade img:gt(0)').hide("");
setInterval(function(){$('.efectfade > :first-
child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.efectfade');}, 
5000);
});
```

css

```
 .efectfade {background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity:0.8;
   height: 100%;}
```

and html

```
<div class="efectfade">

       <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/304390/ss_f49a29395ae871
              76ee986dc16eddf9c4a3285231.1920x1080.jpg?t=1511961587">
<img src="
 https://fsmedia.imgix.net/95/59/72/bf/16f7/467c/9232/c85b40a56d06/the
         -brutal-centurion-one-of-the-two-new-heroes-playable-in-
    shadow--might.jpeg">
   </div>
```

and here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rypz99/pyxjhfbv/ 
my question how to not flashing when changing image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a brief moment both images are displaying. The image that is fading in is displayed beneath the image that is fading out. The flash you're seeing is the white background of the body.

I believe that one way you can achieve your desired effect is to have a div containing both images absolutely positioned within. Set Image1 to have a higher z-index than image2, and apply a fade animation on Image1.

```js
$(() => {
 $("#container").click(() => {
   setInterval(() => {
     $("#image1").fadeOut()
      setTimeout(() => {
       $("#image1").fadeIn()
      }, 2500)
    }, 5000)
  })
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  position: realative;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1;
  left: 1;
}
#image1 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <image src="http://exchangedownloads.smarttech.com/public/content/a2/a28daee5-573f-4f1d-943d-807b0fc164f5/previews/medium/0001.png" id="image1"/>
  <image src="https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple118/v4/ab/5e/0a/ab5e0a5a-7e10-ba06-5ca4-1cffe0cfd753/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-85-220-0-5.png/200x0w.jpg" id="image2"/>
</div>
```